# Xcode breakpoints missing advertised "speak" feature

Tags: xcode, debugging

In apple docs, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/setting_breakpoint_actions_and_options.html), it says you can enable sounds or spoken text to happen when execution hits a given breakpoint.[image]

But my Xcode doesn't seem to allow for this.  Am I missing something, and how does one specify the text to speak for breakpoint entry.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the debug point edit window select "Log Message" for Action.
In the then appearing options below select "Speak Message".
Type what you want to be spoken and use variables framed by @ like 
The current value of count is @count@
See also:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/28289/debugging-ios-apps-in-xcode-4-5

Answer (score 0):

Your screen shot displays the Debugger Command action, but what happens if you **click** that to show the menu?

[image]

That shows how to get the Sound choice. As for speech, the simplest way is to use the Shell Command choice and the `say` command (`man say` to learn more about it).